# MongoDB connection refused java spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Trying to connect to a mongodb in a remote server in my spring boot application.
Facing the following issue:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.11.2.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Used the following configuration in the application.properties.

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=#####
spring.data.mongodb.database=####
spring.data.mongodb.port=####
spring.data.mongodb.username=####
spring.data.mongodb.password=####
spring.data.mongodb.host=####
```

The mongo db version on the remote server is 3.0.3

Could anyone please let me know what went wrong ?

Comment: Did you add correct port?

Comment: yes i added the correct port i.e 27017

Comment: Please check remote server status by this command. "sudo service MongoDB  status"
If it working fine then most of the time application not connect with remote server.

Comment: The remote machine is centos 7. But the service is running.

Comment: Check your application.properties file values correct or not. Because most of the time this connection refused exception comes when "You have not started your server, Your server is not listening for connections, On Windows servers, the listen backlog queue is full"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked finally.Just needed to set the rule in the iptables-
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT